# Automated function redirection via library wrappers in C

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, wrapper, dynamic-linking

Suppose I have two libraries `libA.so` and `libB.so` as some shared C libraries.

**A** provides functions - *F1, F2, F3*
**B** provides functions - *F2, F3, F4*

**My problem**: Create a thin wrapper library, `libC.so`, which calls *F1* and *F2* from `libA.so` and *F3* and *F4* from `libB.so`.

One method that I know of is to write a function with the same signature in C.c and use `dlopen` inside the functions to call `libA.so` or `libB.so`, respectively.

But this problem feels like something that should be possible to accomplish without writing any additional code and just using the linker tools to redirect functions to the appropriate libraries.

Is it actually possible to create such a library `libC.so` using any automated tools?

This seems like a simple enough problem that others must have thought of before me but I am unable to see how to automatically create such a library nor find any good resources for automated wrapper creators.

Comment: Not really, the canonical way to do this is the first one you mentioned.

Comment: wow, I'm surprised no one else has tried to do some *linker magic* for these situations.

Comment: @AishaTammy well, someone did, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that such wrappers can be easily generated automagically. One existing solution for this is [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) tool. In your case you can use it to generate wrappers with limited interfaces for libA and libB:

```
$ cat libA_syms.txt
f1
f2
$ implib-gen.py --symbol-list libA_syms.txt libA.so
Generating libA.so.tramp.S...
Generating libA.so.init.c...
$ cat libB_syms.txt
f3
f4
$ implib-gen.py --symbol-list libB_syms.txt libB.so
Generating libB.so.tramp.S...
Generating libB.so.init.c...
```

and then use generated code to create a wrapper library:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden libA.so.* libB.so.* -o libC.so
```

See [this file](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so/blob/master/tests/multilib/run.sh) for complete example.

Comment: OMG, yes, I actually did find that repository and was making a port for it in Gentoo Science, but I wasn't able to figure out how to use it and all its various options :O     
I'll ask more on there :)

Comment: @aisha It turned out that stock Implib.so already supported your case so I've provided example in the answer.